# How to write exception in text file and save it in sdcard in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell  How to write exception in text file and save it in sdcard in android

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
try{
..........
}catch(Exception e){
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Log"));     
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
}
```

or check this blog

http://www.digitalprank.org/how-to-redirect-console-output-to-file-using-java/

Comment: will it append or create new?

Comment: When I try this I get cannot convert from Java.IO.FileOutputStream to Java.IO.File

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are trying to implement a crash/error logging system in your application. [this is a superb way to do it](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

or you can always user e.printStackTrace() and convert it to string and write it to a text file on sd card.Look [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/debugging-applications-by-emailing-error-reports/)

for the code and instead of using the email intent just open a .txt file in your SD card and write the string to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a Logger-Class.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Init the logger
    /// </summary>
    public LogUtils()
    {
        String path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/MyAppFolder";

        logFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "LogFile.txt");

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(logFilePath))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Starting logging at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs new messages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public void Log(String message)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + message + "\n");
        }
    }
```

just change the path to your sd-card.

Create a new instance in your OnCreate-Method

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        LogUtils Logger = new LogUtils();
```

and Log the Messages

```
                try
                {
                    ...
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Log(e.Message);
                }
```